# Error when trying to do LDAP lookup in active directory

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to lookup a user on a local active-directory using java.
When I try to execute the code, I get the following error:

Error:

> Lookup failed: javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 -
>   000004DC: Lda pErr: DSID-0C0906DC, comment: In order to perform this
>   operation a successful bi nd must be completed on the connection.,
>   data 0, v1db1 ]; remaining name: 'CN= John Doe, OU=Accounts'

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;    
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;

/**
 * Demonstrates how to look up an object.
 * 
 * usage: java Lookup
 */
class Lookup {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Set up the environment for creating the initial context
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable(11);
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,
                "ldap://localhost:389/DC=PORTAL-UAT,DC=COMPANY,DC=COM");

        try {
            // Create the initial context
            Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);

            // Perform lookup and cast to target type
            LdapContext b = (LdapContext) ctx
                    .lookup("CN=John Doe,OU=Accounts");

            System.out.println(b);

            // Close the context
            ctx.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Lookup failed: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message states you have to perform bind operation, i.e. login into the AD. Here is the [LDAP Authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html) tutorial from Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

The coder should use the `ldapsearch` command line utility to verify that the connection can be
established that the credentials for the bind DN are correct. This low-level approach will
ensure that a connection can be made from the client system to the target directory server. This
is a basic troubleshooting technique.

For more information, see [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)

Comment: -1 I don't see how this answers the question. The error message and the code sample contain enough information for troubleshooting.

Comment: The answer specifically addresses a basic troubleshooting technique, especially when dealing with directory servers, and points to the correct concepts the understanding of which answers the question. If the poster understood the error message, the question would not have been asked. When basic techniques are not explained in detail, the poster is left in the dark with no way to answer his own questions in the future.

Comment: I agree with you, but I think that it is more appropriate first to explain what the error message means then to provide basic troubleshooting techniques, which the poster may or may not already know.

Comment: FYI, I gave the points because I could not establish a bind connection with the ldapsearch comment.

Comment: Since this was helpful I have tried to remove my down-vote but I got the following message `You last voted on this answer
2 hours ago
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited`

Comment: don't worry about it. you probably have better things to do, anyway :)